# Crontab Output in Linux

Tags: linux, cron

I've created a crontab with some attributes, but i need it to insert the execute time into an output named output.out, how can i do that?

Comment: For clarity, please put your original question back the way it was, with your editions as an edit. The answers now make no sense.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: The user edited the question. It was originally about how to create a crontab with particular properties. Crontabs obviously use bash to run the command, which is a scripting language and definitely a programming question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

using https://crontab-generator.org/

Put the following in your crontab:

```
*/10 13-15 * * 1-5 run_command >> logfile
```

An explanation:

```
*/10 - every 10 minutes
13-15 - from 1-3 pm
* - every day
* - every every month
1-5 - monday through friday
\>> - bash append (will add to file, not overwrite on every run)
```

Simply have your script write to std out when it runs and the output will log the times. If you don't have that option you could run

```
*/10 13-15 * * 1-5 run_command; date >> logfile
```

Which should echo the date and time to your logfile when the command is executed.